# Showing Riemann integrability

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded.  Show that $f$ is Riemann intergrable iff $$\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} f = -\left[\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} -f\right]$$

My attempt is as follows.

"$\Leftarrow$"
$$\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} -f= \inf\{U(-f;P)\}=\inf\{-L(f;P)\}$$

So,

$$-[\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} -f = -[-\sup\{L(f;P)\}]=\sup\{f;P\}$$

I'm stuck on making sure I'm pushing definitions through properly and the $\to$ direction of the proof.

Comment: I think your reasoning is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanded version:

\begin{align}
\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} f &= -\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} -f \\
                     &= -\inf\{\sum (x_i-x_{i-1}) \sup_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} (-f(x)) \} \\
                     &= -\inf\{-\sum (x_i-x_{i-1}) \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x) \} \\
                     &= \sup\{\sum (x_i-x_{i-1}) \inf_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x) \} \\
                     &= \mbox{lower integral} \\
\end{align}

So that equation is equivalent to Riemann integrability.

Comment: I'm trying to prove this identity: $\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} f = -\bar{\int_{a}^{b}} -f$.  I'm stuck on messing with definitions of upper integrals.

Comment: @emka: Did you read my answer? It handles both directions.